# Iterate through a 2D array as if it were a 1D array using Iterator

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, iterator

I'm a beginner in Java and I have to recieve values from such thing as `Iterator<Iterator<Integer>>`. For example, we may have:

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
```

The result of `next()` should be `1`. If we try `next()` one more time - `2`, then - `3`, `4`, etc. Like getting values from 1D array one by one, but from 2D array. We should **not copy** anything. So, I wrote some bad code below:

```
public class IteratorNext {

    private Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> values = null;
    private Iterator<Integer> current;

    public IteratorNext(Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> iterator) {
        this.values = iterator;
    }

    public int next() throws NoSuchElementException {
        current = values.next();
        if (!current.hasNext()) {
            values.next();
        }
        if (!values.hasNext() && !current.hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Reached end");
        }
        return current.next();
    }
}
```

That code is not correct, because result of `next()` is `1`, then `3`, then `5` and because of exception here. How to fix this?

Comment: Are you using `java-8`? There is a simpler way to do this then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using *Java-8*, you can take advantage of the `flatMapToInt` function to iron out your 2D array into a 1D array (`array2d` can be assumed to be a reference to your 2D array) :

```
Arrays.stream(array2d).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).forEach(System.out::println);
```

if you want to stick to your solution, you need to modify your `next` method as follows :

```
public int next() throws NoSuchElementException {
    int result = -1;
    //Are we already iterating one of the second dimensions?
    if(current!=null && current.hasNext()) {
        //get the next element from the second dimension.
        result =  current.next();
    } else if(values != null && values.hasNext()) {
        //get the next second dimension
        current = values.next();
        if (current.hasNext()) {
            //get the next element from the second dimension
            result =  current.next();
        } 
    } else {
        //we have iterated all the second dimensions
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Reached end");
    }

    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class IteratorNext {

    private Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> values = null;
    private Iterator<Integer> current;

    public IteratorNext(Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> iterator) {
        this.values = iterator;
    }

    public int next() throws NoSuchElementException {

        if (current != null && current.hasNext()) {
            Integer val = current.next();
            return val;
        }

        if (values != null && values.hasNext()) {
            current = values.next();
            if (current != null && current.hasNext()) {
                Integer val = current.next();
                return val;
            }
        }

        throw new NoSuchElementException("Reached end");

    }
}
```

Comment: The `null` check on the `current` in the third `if` condition is not really required since `current` represents an `Iterator` that can never be `null`.

Comment: It would be nice if you'd explain your modification.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call next(), you have to deal with the result.

The first line of your next() method you skip the first element because you recall current.next() at the end of your next() method.

More generally speaking this code is not the right way to deal with collections. You have to analyze the problem in term of usage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each time you call next() you start with

```
 current = values.next();
```

So at each call you skip to the next iterator, without trying to continue iteration on current.

Instead you should do something like

```
if(!current.hasNext())
   current = values.next();
```